# Directrix of a hyperbola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I have been told that the directrix of a hyperbola is given as $$x = \pm\frac{a^2}{c}.$$

I cannot find any simple but convincing proof of this anywhere.

The hyperbola is of the form $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1.$$

Can anyone help with a proof of this?

Comment: You might want to say where the variable $c$ came from. If it's just an arbitrary real number, the $a^2$ in the directrix formula would be redundant. Also, in order to make it possible to read your formulas easily, see the advice at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Definition_of_a_hyperbola_by_the_directrix_property

Comment: c is the location of the focal point of a hyperbola. In this case (c, 0) along the x axis, and of course (-c, 0) as well.

Comment: Hi amd Unfortunately the material on Wikipedia starts with the assumption that the equation for both directrix is $a^2/c$ rather than showing that this is true.

Comment: I have solved this problem below, please verify it from your end

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that conjugate axis is parallel to y axis, hence the directrix equation is : x-T=0 , 
$\frac{(x_1-c)^2+y_1^2}{(x_1-T)^2}=e^2$, 
$a^2+b^2=c^2$ & c=ae, 
Solving we get T= $\frac{a^2}{c}$ 
As Hyperbola has two directrix other is negative of it

Comment: Using $(x_1,y_1)=(a,0)$ you only need $(a-c)=\epsilon(T-a)$, $c=a\epsilon$ to deduce the result.

Comment: Hi Samar - thanks for your response. I can see how you arrived at your equation for e^2 but cannot see how you are going to solve for T eliminating the variables x and y. 

Another related question - your solution (assuming we can solve for T) relies on c = ae. How can we prove c = ae for a hyperbola?